# Get link of the page that createWindow() opens

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to make a tab system

This code gives me the link of the page that i am currently on, i would like to get the link of the page i clicked on. In this code if i change `return nullptr;` to `return this;`, the clicked page will open in the same tab.

```
QWebEngineView* createWindow(QWebEnginePage::WebWindowType type)
{
    if(type == QWebEnginePage::WebBrowserTab)
    {
        emit new_url(this->url());
        return nullptr;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

What does `return` mean in the QWebEngineView::createWindow() function?

How could i get the link i clicked on?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little change worked for me:

```
QWebEngineView* createWindow(QWebEnginePage::WebWindowType type)
{
    if(type == QWebEnginePage::WebBrowserTab)
    {
       MyWebView *webView = new MyWebView();
        emit new_tab(webView);
        return webView;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

this code creates a new `MyWebView` object and send it to another function i implemented to create tabs and finally, `return webView` opens the new link in the `webView` object